# how to create viewhelpers with twig

Tags: php, twig, fluid, viewhelper

I am using Twig on a standalone basis without symfony.
I made lots of templates that all work just fine. I have been trying to build a viewhelper just like in Fluid.
I wanted to create a viewhelper which basically just wraps a text with some html tags or what ever i like, but twig always seems to htmlspecialchars() whatever i am trying to do.
What i have tried sofar:

```
    // ...
    $twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('test2',function($one){
        return '<h1> '.$one.' </h1>';
    }));
    // ...
    $twig->addFunction('displayResponseMessage', new Twig_Function_Function('displayResponseMessage'));
    // ...
```

I'm clueless. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your issue, you should provide the `is_safe` option:

```
$twig->addFunction(new Twig_SimpleFunction('test2',function($one){
    return '<h1> '.$one.' </h1>';
}), array('is_safe' => array('html'));
```

Check out the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html).

Anyway, I suggest you to look at the [import tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html), as Twig already handle your requirement.